# How can I get the top 5 movie genres for the Unites States from my movie data frame by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a movie data frame where I want to extract the top 5 movie genres of the United States, I thought about using group by, however, it doesn't work as it considered my genre column (listed_in) as a string. How could this be done?

Here is what is tried:

```
netflix_df.groupby(['country']['listed_in']).count().sort_values(ascending = False).head(5)
```

Data frame information:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8807 entries, 0 to 8806
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   show_id       8807 non-null   object
 1   type          8807 non-null   object
 2   title         8807 non-null   object
 3   director      6173 non-null   object
 4   cast          7982 non-null   object
 5   country       7976 non-null   object
 6   date_added    8797 non-null   object
 7   release_year  8807 non-null   int32 
 8   rating        8803 non-null   object
 9   duration      8804 non-null   object
 10  listed_in     8807 non-null   object
dtypes: int32(1), object(10)
memory usage: 722.6+ KB
```

Snippet of the dataframe

0   s1  Movie   Dick Johnson Is Dead    Kirsten Johnson NaN United States   September 25, 2021  2020    PG-13   90 min  Documentaries

1   s2  TV Show Blood & Water   NaN Ama Qamata, Khosi Ngema, Gail Mabalane, Thaban...   South Africa    September 24, 2021  2021    TV-MA   2 Seasons   International TV Shows, TV Dramas, TV Mysteries

2   s3  TV Show Ganglands   Julien Leclercq Sami Bouajila, Tracy Gotoas, Samuel Jouy, Nabi...   NaN September 24, 2021  2021    TV-MA   1 Season    Crime TV Shows, International TV Shows, TV Act...

3   s4  TV Show Jailbirds New Orleans   NaN NaN NaN September 24, 2021  2021    TV-MA   1 Season    Docuseries, Reality TV

4   s5  TV Show Kota Factory    NaN Mayur More, Jitendra Kumar, Ranjan Raj, Alam K...   India   September 24, 2021  2021    TV-MA   2 Seasons   International TV Shows, Romantic TV Shows, TV

Comment: Could we have access to the top-10 as a csv/df format to be sure before answering with the right code? With addition to what would be the outcome you're looking for please ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, however for the outcome it would be something like Fiction, Action, Thriller, Comedy, Romantic

Comment: Print your data frame in copy paste it there within your post.

Comment: ok, I've put it up now, but I'm not sure how to format it better

Comment: See @Artur's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter with [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then use [.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

For example:

```
netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'] == 'US']['listed_in'].value_counts()[:5]
```

If you want to extract the values or the indexes in a list:

```
# values
netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'] == 'US']['listed_in'].value_counts()[:5].tolist()
# indexes
netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'] == 'US']['listed_in'].value_counts()[:5].index.tolist()
```

#Edit

Asking the question, if your genre field have more than one, you have to split the string, iterate through them and store the count in some way. I have developed a little function that may help you.

```
def getGenres(series):
    genres = {}

    for row in series:
        if isinstance(row, str):
            genreList = row.split(',')
            for genre in genreList:
                if genre.strip().title() in genres:
                    genres[genre.strip().title()] += 1
                else:
                    genres[genre.strip().title()] = 1       
    
    return genres
```

Then, just

```
getGenres(netflix_df.loc[netflix_df['country'] == 'US']['listed_in'])
```

And to sort a dict by value check it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Thank you, this works, however some genres of my columns have multiple genres listed separated by command.  For example: International TV Shows, TV Dramas, TV Mysteries. Would it be possible to take those in account as I assume what happens here is that is takes the whole as a string

Comment: I edited the comment with a possible solution. @Juliette